# A way to persist TreeNode from Primefaces with JPA

Tags: jpa, primefaces, treenode

Is there anyway i can use the primefaces TreeNode/DefaultTreeNode class with JPA for persistence?

I'm trying to do it, but i'm completely lost.
I think I might have to implement my own TreeNode class to do that, but I did want to use primefaces class for using with the p:treeNode component.

Answer (score 0):

I would not persist treenodes for since most likely the only way you can get them persisted is to have them serialized which will (99% chance) lead to problems in the future if PF changes something in the DefaultTreeNode.

More generically, I would never persist objects not from my own model!

As you can see in [this example in the PF showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/selection.xhtml) you can add your own entities to the treenode when building them

```
TreeNode documents = new DefaultTreeNode(new Document("Documents", "-", "Folder"), root);
```

On selection you can get the object back by `node.getData()`

Comment: Thanks man, I'll try storing parent and children objects in my model then.